# Call angular method in chrome extension popup page when popup page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I'm writing a chrome extension that uses angularjs to get a JSON response from an API. The page bellow is the popup for the extension. At the moment there is a form that calls a method in the angular controller to get the JSON from the API, however I would like to have this called when the popup is opened. I have tried many things to get this to work and failed. I'd like some guidance if anyone knows what is required to achieved what I want.

Thanks.

Here's my code.

I declare my app like so

```
var extension = angular.module('StackAPI',['ngResource']);
```

In my controller file i have the following.

```
extension.controller('StackAPICtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {

    $scope.stackAPI = $resource('http://*/question/params?questionId=:questionId',
        {port:'80', questionId:'', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP'}});
    $scope.doSearch = function () {
        $scope.soResult = $scope.stackAPI.get({questionId:$scope.search});
    }
});
```

And my html popup page looks like this

The form with the `ng-submit="doSearch()"` is what currently calls the method in the angular controller. I would like this method `doSearch()` to be called when I open the extension popup page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="StackAPI" ng-csp>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/extension.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/query.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/all.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="StackAPICtrl">

    <form align="left" ng-submit="doSearch()">
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a question id..." ng-model="search" size="115">
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="answer in soResult.answers">
            <div id="answer-{{answer.answer_id}}" class="answer" data-answerid={{answer.answer_id}}>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="votecell">
                        <div class="vote">
                            <span class="vote-count-post " title="up-ranked">
                                <img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="arrow" height="64" width="64">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="answercell" align="left">
                        <div class="post-text" ng-bind-html-unsafe="answer.body">

                        </div>
                        <table class="fw">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vt">
                                    <div class="post-menu">
                                        <a class="short-link">share</a>
                                        <span class="lsep">|</span>
                                        <a class="suggest-edit-post" title="revise and improve this post">edit</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" class="post-signature">
                                    <div class="user-info ">
                                        <div class="user-action-time">answered {{answer.creation_date}}
                                            <span title="2013-02-22 23:12:55Z" class="relativetime"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user-gravatar32">
                                            <!-- ${profile_picture} -->
                                            <img src="{{answer.owner.profile_image}}"
                                                 alt="" width="32" height="32">
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- users details stuff here -->
                                        <div class="user-details">
                                            <!-- ${name} -->
                                            <a>{{answer.owner.display_name}}</a><br>
                                <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score" dir="ltr">
                                <!-- ${reputation} -->
                                    {{answer.owner.reputation}}
                                </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not understand when you want the method will be called and when it is called now in practice. You can mark it in code?

Comment: I edited my question, is it clearer now?

Comment: Another small question when doSearch method is called now?

Comment: The doSearch method is called with the form is submitted. Currently I open the popup by clicking on the extension icon and enter value in the input field and submit the form

Comment: Couldn't you just throw the `doSearch()` into say `popup.js` and include it in a script tag. It would be loaded and executed every time you opened the popup.

Comment: the `doSearch()` is in a js file, it is part of an angular controller. I have tried doing just what you suggested, but there is some scoping issue that I'm not totally sure how to get around. As I said, I have tried many things to get this to work, all have failed. I need someone who knows what the problem is to help

Comment: I didn't mean putting the method in a new file. I meant putting the call in one. Put just `doSearch();` in `/js/popup.js` and then add `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popup.js"></script>` after the other scripts.

Comment: I want to be sure I understood correctly, now the `doSearch()` is sent by sending the form as it sits in `ng-submit`, right? you want to put this function instead of `ng-submit` in attr that it called when the form opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I am doing is not possible with my current setup due to the content security policy (CSP) chrome has. The API I created is currently serving only with http, this is where the problem lies. The `doSearch()` method calls a ngResource that has been initialized with my http API and due to the CSP it can only run in a sandbox defined in the manifest file. The sandboxing means other parts of the extension can not comuiniacte with what ever is running in the sandbox, and so I can not call the `doSearch()` method in the way that I want.

The solution to this - I have to configure tomcat to serve the API over https, which is allowed by the CSP once the source uri is stated in the manifest file.